# pandas plot dataframe as multiple bar charts

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot

This is my pandas dataframe `df`:

```
          ab             channel   booked
0    control             book_it     466
1    control          contact_me     536
2    control             instant     17
3  treatment             book_it     494
4  treatment          contact_me     56
5  treatment             instant     22
```

I want to plot 3 groups of bar chart (according to `channel`):

for each channel:
plot control booked value vs treatment booked value.

hence i should get 6 bar charts, in 3 groups where each group has control and treatment booked values.

SO far i was only able to plot booked but not grouped by ab:

```
ax = df_conv['booked'].plot(kind='bar',figsize=(15,10), fontsize=12)
ax.set_xlabel('dim_contact_channel',fontsize=12)
ax.set_ylabel('channel',fontsize=12)
plt.show()
```

[image]

This is what i want (only show 4 but this is the gist):
[image]

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Pivot the dataframe so control and treatment values are in separate columns.

```
df.pivot(index='channel', columns='ab', values='booked').plot(kind='bar')
```

[image: bar plot]

Comment: How can i rotate the x axis values?

Comment: @jxn Look at the docs for `DataFrame.plot()`. Passing `rot=0` should do. If you are still in trouble ask another question.