# Python plot bar chart with group

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have the following dataframe:
[image]

I'm trying to plot a bar chart, with x as 'config names', y as 'value', and one bar per month (one bin per month). I'm not sure how to do this, any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have your data in a pandas DataFrame (let's say `df`), it's rather easy:

```
import seaborn as sns

sns.barplot(x='config names', y='value', data='df')
```

I'm not sure what you mean by *one bin per month*. The bins here are your *x* axis.

If you mean you want to split different months into different bins then you should just add them to the *hue* parameter.

```
import seaborn as sns

sns.barplot(x='config names', y='value', data='df', hue='month')
```

Answer (score 0):

I may not understand what you ask but it looks like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35248976/pandas-plot-dataframe-as-multiple-bar-charts) 
So I suggest you do a pivot table with your dataframe.
Let's say your dataframe variable name is df, can you try this :

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

pt_df = pd.pivot_table(
  df, 
  values=['value'], 
  columns=['month'], 
  aggfunc=np.sum
).plot(kind='bar')
```