# Plot a bar chart with different legend colors

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, plot

I am trying to plot a chart. I can plot a line chart which can show 5 different color with 5 legend. I want to plot a bar chart which can show 5 different colors, but the bar chart I plot has only 1 color, may I know what's wrong with my code?

Here is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib as plt

df = pd.read_csv('df.csv')
df.set_index('date',inplace=True)

date        symbol  roe
31/12/2015  NEM -0.9866
31/12/2016  NEM -6.8385
31/12/2017  NEM -0.6164
31/12/2018  NEM 2.7824
31/12/2019  NEM 13.2141
31/12/2015  MLM 7.1164
31/12/2016  MLM 10.27
31/12/2017  MLM 15.2355
31/12/2018  MLM 9.5042
31/12/2019  MLM 11.4322
30/9/2015   APD 13.0861
30/9/2016   APD 15.5544
30/9/2017   APD 11.3416
30/9/2018   APD 13.3381
30/9/2019   APD 15.8882
31/12/2015  VMC 5.2291
31/12/2016  VMC 9.238
31/12/2017  VMC 11.9421
31/12/2018  VMC 9.9529
31/12/2019  VMC 11.0729
31/12/2015  FMC -11.1408
31/12/2016  FMC 6.558
31/12/2017  FMC -4.9167
31/12/2018  FMC 16.7456
31/12/2019  FMC 21.2189
```

I can plot a line chart:-

```
df.groupby('symbol')['roe'].plot(figsize=(10,8),legend='True')
```

[image]

I can plot a chart, but I want the chart have 5 different bar on each year with different color. May I know how to solve this?

```
df.groupby('symbol')['roe'].plot(kind='bar', legend='True', figsize = (5,5))
```

[image]

Comment: You want different color for the years or for the symbols?

Comment: hello, I want on each year there has 5 different charts with 5 different colors. Thank you in advance.

Comment: [Like this?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35249103/8881141)

Comment: Yes, thank you for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's try groupby the year and plot:

```
for y,d in df.groupby(pd.to_datetime(df['date']).dt.year):
    ax = d.pivot('date','symbol','roe').plot.bar()
    ax.set_title(y)
```

You will have five different plots, each for a year that looks like this:

[image]

If you want to plot all of them into one plot, skip the `groupby`, just pivot and plot:

```
df.pivot('date','symbol','roe').plot.bar()
```

and get

[image]

Comment: may i know is there has a function to remove the month and day on the datetime column? There has one issue with the symbol APD which the month and day is different with those 4 symbols. Thank you in advance x

Comment: `df['date'].dt.year` if your `date` columns is of datetime type.